# How to get the length of written bytes with BinaryWriter?

Tags: c#, binarywriter

Considering a simple BinaryWriter procedure:

```
using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Create)))
        {
            writer.Write(10000);
            writer.Write("Temp");
            writer.Write(30);
            writer.Write(50.6);
        }
```

Now, how can I get the total number of written bytes by the BinaryWriter? And how to append this amount to the current writer object, e.g. writer.Write(totalNumberAsBytes)

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried `writer.BaseStream.Length`? This should be the amount of bytes in the stream.